# One controller for different views MVC

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core

I would like to know if it is best to use One controller for multiple views that load approximately the same data or use one controller for every view.

And if  it is possible to use the controller like this :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class MultiplePagesController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetA()
        { ... return viewA }

        [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetB()
    { ... return viewB }
}
```

And in my serviceViewA.ts :

```
getA() {
        return this.http.get<InterfaceA>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/multiplepages/`);
    }
```

My serviceViewB.ts :

```
getB() {
            return this.http.get<InterfaceB>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/multiplepages/`);
        }
```

Since let's say the viewA returns data of books and the viewB returns data of books and computers.

I am using MVC .NET CORE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in fact a great idea to use one controller (and method) if it does exactly the same thing, you reduce code this way, makes it easy to maintain and modify in just one place rather than all over the project. Think of it as a container for your functions. If you have a Book controller, you put all methods related to books there, same for User, you would put all user methods there.

As for your second question, that goes against polymorphism. Your function signatures are exactly the same, how will it be distinguished? You'll need to give it a different name or accept a parameter (different from the other function or different data type).

Worth noting that you can name your function differently to return views.

For example:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetViewA(){ // ... }

public async Task<IActionResult> GetViewB(){ // ... }
```

You'll call those views by entering: `/Controller/GetViewB` as your path.

Comment: Whoever down-voted, at least say what you don't agree on. Pointless to down-vote for no obvious reason and no explanation...

Comment: So I manage to make it work. But I still have doubt about using only one controller. If the function GetViewA gets only books and the function GetViewB gets books and computers, what do you think I should do ? I have the same question for the service that calls my controller.

Comment: Have two function on the controller? They do two different things? You need to decide what's the most efficient design for your controllers. You want to reduce the amount of code that does exactly the same thing.

Comment: I will have 4 functions in the controller and will load books in the first, books/computer in the second, books/computers in the third and books/images in the fourth. So I don't think I have to create 4 different controllers, have I ?

Comment: No, you would create one controller called e.g. Books and put your methods there... you use your controller to group methods of similar functionality by what they represent. So for example a Book or User and you have methods that deal with User or a Book...

Comment: Ok, i will see what suits best. Thank you